# Using classes to define GUI in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to simplify progress bars in Unity as well as some other features but they aren't showing when I instantiate them. Here's what I have so far. What am I not doing that's making this not work?

Bar.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bar : MonoBehaviour {

    private float x,y,w,h;
    private string text;
    private int barCap;
    private int curr;

    bool refSet = false;
    public bool visible = true;

    public Bar(float xIn, float yIn, float wIn, float hIn, string textIn)
    {
        this.x = xIn;
        this.y = yIn;
        this.w = wIn;
        this.h = hIn;
        this.text = textIn;     
    }

    public void setRef(int value, int amount)
    {
        this.barCap = value;
        this.curr = amount;
        this.refSet = true;
    }

    void OnGUI () 
    {
        if(refSet && visible)
        {
            Debug.Log("Getting hit");
            GUI.Box (new Rect(x,y,w,h),text);
            GUI.Box (new Rect(x,y,(w/barCap)*curr,h),"");
        }
    }   
}
```

Main.cs

```
...
private Bar hpBar;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    //HP Bar
    hpBar = new Bar((ScreenWidth - ((barWidth + (padding * 3))*2)),(ScreenHeight - (boxBGHeight - padding * 3)), 100, 30, "HP");
    hpBar.setRef(HP, currHP);
}
...
```

EDIT:

I used this `hpBar = gameObject.AddComponent("Bar") as Bar;` in the `Start()` of Main.cs
to init a bar, then in the `OnGUI()` I set the reference and changed the constructor into a function to set the variables:

```
hpBar.setBar(ScreenWidth - ((barWidth + (padding * 3))*2),ScreenHeight - (boxBGHeight - padding * 5),barWidth,barHeight,"HP");
            hpBar.setRef(HP,currHP);
```

I could probably put this into the `Update()` to happen every loop (even though OnGUI does too). The main script is on an empty gameobject so i just added it to self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't `new` MonoBehaviours, you attach them to GameObjects in your scene. Pick a GameObject, attach a `Bar` to it and move on from there. If you want to have a single script manage your `Bar`s, do it like this:

```
//Inside the script that manages bars.
public Bar hpBar; //Set this reference in the editor.

void Start () 
{
    hpBar.setPositionAndStuff(...);
    hpBar.setRef(HP, currHP);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to instantiate a bar object and have it show without having to have a gameobject waiting in the scene? It feels dirty to me and would rather have it organized in script than just objects in the hierarchy.

Comment: The best you can do is attach Bar scripts to the same GameObject that you attached the bar manager to. Or treat each bar as a non-MonoBehavior (i.e. dumb objects that only hold bar info), and do all of the drawing based on their info in the bar manager. But to put it simply, no, you cannot use Start, OnGUI and all of the other methods that are automatically called by Unity in non-attached scripts.